# Converting number range score to a letter grade in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

Confused why I'm getting this error message. I am looking at a range of possible outcomes for grades and want to return the letter grade in column A. I've never seen this message before.

[image]

Comment: In Cell H22 is the result from adding F22 + G22

Answer (score 0):

Why not better use :`=INDEX($A$3:$A$7,MATCH(H22,$B$3:$B$7,-1))`?